# How to setup a SSH connection using a variable hostname provided by jump server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to create a .sshconfig file for the case where I need to connect to a login node (the jump server), get the hostname from that node by running a command, and then ssh to that hostname using the same username and credentials I used for the login node. This is the config I have ended up with:

```
Host jump-server
  HostName loginnode
  User user

Host remote
  User user
  IdentityFile C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
  ProxyCommand ssh -q jump-server "ssh user@`command_to_get_the_hostname` bash -l"
```

I am trying to ssh using this command:
`ssh.exe -v remote`

And I am getting this output:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config line 14: Applying options for remote
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q jump-server "ssh lemoni15@`command_to_get_the_hostname` bash -l"
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
: command not foundSH_for_Windows_8.1
```

Answer (score 2):

### `RemoteCommand`

You said only the jump host knows the hostname of the remote host, right? The `ProxyCommand` runs on the local machine, so it will never run the `command_to_get_the_hostname` on the jump host. In order to first connect to the jump host and then run the command there, you might use `RemoteCommand` instead.

> `RemoteCommand`
>
> Specifies a command to execute on the remote machine after successfully connecting to the server. The command string extends to the end of the line, and is executed with the user's shell. - -

E.g.

```
Host remote
  Hostname jump-host.example.com
  User user
  RemoteCommand ssh user@$(/full/path/to/command_to_get_the_hostname)
```

Now you can connect to the remote host using `ssh -t remote`, where the `-t` *forces pseudo-terminal allocation* for running the `$(command)` on the remote side i.e. on the jump host.

As a side effect, you won't be able to use the local `IdentityFile C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa` for the remote host, but the jump host must have the key, as the second `ssh` is now running on the jump host.

### `ProxyJump` & scripting

If you would like to use the jump host as a `ProxyJump` (`-J`) host, being able to use the local `IdentityFile` (`-i`), `ForwardX11` (`-X`), `ForwardX11Trusted` (`-Y`) etc., some scripting would be required instead of using just the SSH configuration file. You would first need to connect to the jump host, get the remote host address from there, and then use it in another SSH connection.

With **Bash** this would be something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

remotehost=$(\
  ssh user@jump-host.example.com \
  /full/path/to/command_to_get_the_hostname) || exit 1

ssh -X -Y -J user@jump-host.example.com \
  -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@"$remotehost"
```

I *think* this could be turned into a **PowerShell** script on Windows (didn't test):

```
$remoteHost = ssh.exe user@jump-host.example.com `
  /full/path/to/command_to_get_the_hostname
if (-not $?) {throw "Failed to get the remote hostname"}

ssh.exe -X -Y -J user@jump-host.example.com `
  -i "C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa" "user@$remoteHost"
```